# Array Elements as Case in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

I am creating this javascript game but first I need the user to decide what branch of the military (s)he will use.  The problem is my switch function won't do anything!  **It is very frustrating!**
P.S. Most of the ranks code is actual in other js files and they are all tied into the body of html.

```
var AUS1=["Doku Umarov",25,25,.45,.10,50,.150];
var AUS2=["Abubakar Shekau",38,25,.50,.15,50,.175];
var AUS3=["Sirajuddin Haqqani",50,25,.55,.20,50,.200];
var AUS4=["Abu Bakr al-Baghdadi",63,50,.60,.25,75,.225];
var AUS5=["Abu Muhammad al-Julani",75,50,.65,.30,75,.250];
var AUS6=["Moktar Belmoktar",88,50,.70,.35,75,.375];
var AUS7=["Ahmed Abdi Godane",100,75,.75,.40,100,.400];
var AUS8=["Ibrahim al-Asiri",113,75,.80,.45,100,.425];
var AUS9=["Nasir al Wuhayshi",125,75,.85,.50,100,.450];
var AUS10=["Ayman al-Zawahiri",138,100,.90,.55,200,.475];
var AUSBoss=["Satan",150,100,.95,.60,500,.500];

var AF2L=["Second Lieutenant",25,25,.45,.10,50,.150];
var AF1L=["First Lieutenant",38,25,.50,.15,50,.175];
var AFCpt=["Captain",50,25,.55,.20,50,.200];
var AFMjr=["Major",63,50,.60,.25,75,.225];
var AFLC=["Lieutenant Colonel",75,50,.65,.30,75,.250];
var AFCnl=["Colonel",88,50,.70,.35,75,.375];
var AFBG=["Brigadier General",100,75,.75,.40,100,.400];
var AFMG=["Major General",113,75,.80,.45,100,.425];
var AFLG=["Lieutenant General",125,75,.85,.50,100,.450];
var AFG=["General",138,100,.90,.55,200,.475];
var GoAF=["General of the Air Force",150,100,.95,.60,500,.500];

var A2L=["Second Lieutenant",25,25,.45,.10,50,.150];
var A1L=["First Lieutenant",38,25,.50,.15,50,.175];
var ACpt=["Captain",50,25,.55,.20,50,.200];
var AMjr=["Major",63,50,.60,.25,75,.225];
var ALC=["Lieutenant Colonel",75,50,.65,.30,75,.250];
var ACnl=["Colonel",88,50,.70,.35,75,.375];
var ABG=["Brigadier General",100,75,.75,.40,100,.400];
var AMG=["Major General",113,75,.80,.45,100,.425];
var ALG=["Lieutenant General",125,75,.85,.50,100,.450];
var AG=["General",138,100,.90,.55,200,.475];
var GoA=["General of the Army",150,100,.95,.60,500,.500];

var NEns=["Ensign",25,25,1,.10,50,.150];
var NLJ=["Lieutenant Junior Grade",38,25,.50,.15,50,.175];
var NLt=["Lieutenant",50,25,.55,.20,50,.200];
var NLC=["Lieutenant Colonel",63,50,.60,.25,75,.225];
var NCnl=["Colonel",75,50,.65,.30,75,.250];
var NCpt=["Captain",88,50,.70,.35,75,.375];
var NRAL=["Rear Admiral Lower Half",100,75,.75,.40,100,.400];
var NRA=["Rear Admiral",113,75,.80,.45,100,.425];
var NVA=["Vice Admiral",125,75,.85,.50,100,.450];
var NFA=["Fleet Admiral",138,100,.90,.55,200,.475];
var SecNav=["Secretary of the Navy",150,100,.95,.60,500,.500];

var alive=true;
var aProb,aProb2,dProb,dProb2,sProb,sProb2,attack,defend,special,rank,q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o,p,a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,z,x,c,v,b,n,m;
var army=[A2L,A1L,ACpt,AMjr,ALC,ACnl,ABG,AMG,ALG,AG,GoA];
var navy=[NEns,NLJ,NLt,NLC,NCnl,NCpt,NRAL,NRA,NVA,NFA];
var air=[AF2L,AF1L,AFCpt,AFMjr,AFLC,AFCnl,AFBG,AFMG,AFLG,AFG,GoAF];
var bads=[AUS1,AUS2,AUS3,AUS4,AUS5,AUS6,AUS7,AUS8,AUS9,AUS10,AUSBoss];
var branch=[army,navy,air];
var name=prompt("Enter your name","NAME").toUpperCase();
var qbranch=prompt("Choose your military branch","AIR,ARMY,NAVY").toLowerCase();
while(alive===true){
switch(qbranch){
    case 'army':
        rank=branch[0][0][0];
        alert(rank);
        break;
    case 'navy':
        rank=branch[1][0][0];
        alert(rank);
        break;
    case 'air':
        rank=branch[2][0][0];
        alert(rank);
        break;
    default:
        qbranch='navy';
        rank=branch[1][0][0];
        alert(rank);
}
alive=false;
}
```

***EDIT***
I want to focus on the switch, why isn't it working?

Comment: Learn how objects works, that way you can use keys to directly access the data instead.

Comment: `branch[0]` is an Array (actually it's undefined, but ignoring that). switch case only works with strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your branch declaration to after your other definitions:

```
var army = [A2L, A1L, ACpt, AMjr, ALC, ACnl, ABG, AMG, ALG, AG, GoA];
var navy = [NEns, NLJ, NLt, NLC, NCnl, NCpt, NRAL, NRA, NVA, NFA];
var air = [AF2L, AF1L, AFCpt, AFMjr, AFLC, AFCnl, AFBG, AFMG, AFLG, AFG, GoAF];
var branch = [army, navy, air];
```

And you're going to have to directly specify the name of the units in your `switch` as a string:

```
case 'army':
```

for example.

I also agree with adeneo that using an object to contain those arrays is much more suitable.

```
var obj = {
  army: {
    A2L: ["Second Lieutenant", 25, 25, .45, .10, 50, .150],
    A1L: ["First Lieutenant", 38, 25, .50, .15, 50, .175],
    ACpt: ["Captain", 50, 25, .55, .20, 50, .200],
    AMjr: ["Major", 63, 50, .60, .25, 75, .225]
    ...
  }
}

obj.army.A2L[0]; // Second Lieutenant
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xkco1rpz/)

Comment: After a bit of jerry-rigging, I have succeeded!  Thanks-a-million guys.